# Pain reliever - For when you want to rid yourself of a downward facing question

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

When a question is [closed] there is no way for the owner to delete it for 2 days.

Even if no answers were given, it sits there like a duck, sitting as it would. And, just like a sitting duck, suffers the hit of other users being allowed to downvote it.

Can this unfairness be addressed somehow?

Comment: @random: That's a great edit. Thanks!

Comment: Note that it appears that people will continue downvoting the question even after it is closed.

Comment: When I'm old, my favourite expression to croak at youngsters is going to be: "There's no fair this year."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this unfairness be addressed
>   somehow?

In short, no. Mostly because it also works the other way. Sometimes things get closed unfairly, and allowing for votes gives the community a chance to "appeal" the close.

Other times, a quality edit will reverse the "bad karma" and garner up-votes, positive attention, and possibly even a re-open.

On the other hand, [as waffles mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41964/pain-reliever-for-when-you-want-to-rid-yourself-of-a-downward-facing-question/41965#41965), if there was a little more tact in the questions that seem to attract this behaviour then it wouldn't be as big a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just edit and change it to community wiki?

Comment: I do this on bad (that I give) answers instead of deleting them cause I like for all of SO to be left in tact visible to everyone (except for spam)

Comment: It's not an obvious solution and seems a bit like cheating.

Comment: @sneg: no it isn't an overtly obvious solution to edit the question and change to CW. But it certainly isn't cheating. No rep is lost/gained from a CW discussion. My recommendation would be to put more thought into the question (say, less argumentative) and change it to CW. Then plead your case to the mods to have it re-opened. If you decide you really want it deleted before the 2 days are up (because you can still be down-voted on it), then flag your question and plead your case with the mods as to why they should go ahead and remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, don't post questions that attract close votes.

Anyway once its deleted you can ask for a rep recaclc and none of the rep you lost will be counted.

Besides no matter how much you get downvoted, once you reach -1,-2 you start to attract compassion upvotes which cancel everything out rep wise (and usually leave you in front) You really need an atrocious question or answer to attract only downvotes.

Comment: Come on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430021/under-what-circumstances-is-python-preferrable-to-php-for-web-development-and-vi

Comment: Yes, not a perfect question. But someone far away from web dev could be easily wondering about it.

Comment: As it stands you only lost 8 reputation points on this, its clearly not such a big drama.

Comment: Each down-vote actually counts as 2 points. But why prevent the deletion by owner in such cases?

Comment: +1 @waffles: I agree that you should try to ask good questions. However, the question, IMO, had *potential* as a CW discussion. I do feel that some questions are closed when they should probably be moved to CW.

Comment: @waffles ... someone voted to repopen that. Good Grief.