# Closed questions continue to be beaten up by downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, flags

I personally think that if a question ([for example, this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430021/under-what-circumstances-is-python-preferrable-to-php-for-web-development-and-vi)) is closed, it should not allow any further changes: comments, answers, edits, down-votes, or up-votes.  In order to make modifications to a question, it needs to be re-opened.

EDIT: Upon review of answers, I can see the need to allow comments and edits.

So my questions are:

1. Do the down-votes continue to penalize the OP?
2. If the OP is regretting the question (as I understand from [this Meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41964/pain-reliever-for-when-you-want-to-rid-yourself-of-a-downward-facing-question)), can he/she flag the question themselves and ask for it to be removed.

Comment: Users often times do flag their own questions for deletion.

Comment: I say it should still allow edits and comments..

Comment: Okay...I can see the point for allowing edits and comments. Makes sense...

Comment: Some closed questions get a lot of upvotes also.

Comment: ...not to mention reopen votes.

Comment: I have no problem with votes to re-open a question. As I stated, I agree with the need to continue edits and comments on a closed question - I changed my position on that based on the answers I received.

Comment: Why the downvote? And a vote to close? This is a legitimate question with definitive answers that are not commonly known, nor a process completely understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to clarify:

What you're suggesting is a **lock** (which can be added by moderators).

A closed question means that the question *as it stands* is not acceptable at the site, but it may be acceptable upon editing (eg. perhaps we're understanding the question wrong).

As for your actual questions:

1) I believe so, but I'm not 100% sure.
2) Yes, the OP can flag the question and ask for it to be removed if they so wish to do so.

Comment: If a question is deemed unacceptable (therefore receiving down-votes and ultimately closed), then why do we continue to punish the OP by allowing down-votes? I realize it is a double-edged sword - there could be an influx of readers who like the question and want to up-vote it. I would not be opposed to locking out any votes until the question is re-opened, period. If edits are made to the question that make it acceptable, then the OP asks to have it re-opened. He/she does this with the realization that there could be yet more down-votes, but hoping for the up-votes instead.

Comment: That said, I am sure there is an explanation for the way it is done. I'm not necessarily opposed to the current mechanics by any means. Should there be a mention in the FAQ that you can flag your really bad question and ask to have it removed?

Answer (score 2):

Closed questions continue to hit the OP and any answers with downvotes (and upvotes) unless the question is deleted.

The OP can either wait for two days and start the vote to delete process or plead their case to a mod for immediate delete if so badly need/want it off the site.

But edits and comments to a closed question can often point out or fix it up to allow it to be reopened. Taking that away means you leave the OP with no clue as to why they've been closed or any chance to improve it to be a better, more valid (or fitting/suitable) question.