# Why can't I view the revisions of my own deleted answer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, revisions-list

I gave and then deleted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41964/pain-reliever-for-when-you-want-to-rid-yourself-of-a-downward-facing-question/42063#42063), but when I click the [revisions list link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/42063/revisions), I get a page not found error.

Why can't I see the revision history of my own answer?

**UPDATE:** I originally asked this question as a <10k user. Now that I'm over 10k, the latter link works, but I still don't think this is proper behaviour: a user who deleted *their own* post should be able to see that page.

Comment: hmm.  i'd expect you should be able to.  you can access the edit link, can't you?

Comment: @quack: Yes, and the combo box of revisions on that screen works, too. I just can't see the screen with the diff'd revisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed -- this should be possible, since owners can see their own deleted answers.

Revisions to deleted answers are now visible, provided the post has an owner, the post is an answer, and you are the owner.