# When trying to undo an upvote on deleted answer the vote arrow stays gray after the failure

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, deleted-answers, undo

Still using [this deleted question of mine on other site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65/i-have-seen-all-harry-potter-movies-i-have-not-read-single-harry-potter-book-d) to test the Roomba Turbo Charging, I found another glitch in the design.

Was really hard to come with the descriptive title so let me demonstrate in a short vid: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kViC26_OfUs

As you see, while the score correctly "reset" itself back the upvote icon doesn't restore itself and stays in the "off" state.

This does not happen when trying to upvote post I didn't upvote before: icon becomes active, then restores itself back to inactive as it should. This also doesn't happen on ordinary non-deleted answers where the vote is locked.

I'm pretty sure it's not related to the recent changes, those just made me find this glitch now. :)

Comment: @Matt: you're right, sorry about that. Wrong dup, it was about locked questions instead of deleted one. I'm pretty sure I saw this requested already but can't find it.

Comment: The address http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65/i-have-seen-all-harry-potter-movies-i-have-not-read-single-harry-potter-book-d isn't available anymore. But I've managed to reproduce the glitch in my dev environment and am looking into it...

Comment: @m0sa yeah, it's deleted - just create yourself diamond account there and you'll see it. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev 2013.7.4.813

Comment: You forgot to status-complete this. (only tag, it's really fixed :))

Comment: tnx @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: Cheers, happy to cause one more bug to get removed from the list. :)

Comment: Just noticed your new hat... fits you well to be a nurse! ;)