# Can a Moderator undelete all my deleted posts?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Can one of you undelete all my deleted posts on Stack Overflow please?

I need to fix them but I can't undelete them myself.

Comment: Done. There were only two deleted questions on your profile.

Comment: @ Anna Lear Thanks btw where should i post this kind of thing?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com would be best. You can also flag any of your posts if you need to ask the moderators for something.

Comment: XD wrong meta my bad, i thought i did LOL

Answer (score 5):

Flag one of your deleted posts for moderator attention, use the 'other' option and request that it is undeleted, as well as your other deleted posts.

That is a far more direct route than asking on Meta.SE, Stack Overflow moderators are not necessarily reading your post here.

Comment: And of course fix them first, then flag.

Comment: @Bart: you can't edit questions while deleted, I believe.

Comment: Really? That's ... bad.

Comment: Not 100% on this, actually, something vaguely remembered.

Comment: @Bart: ah, this is only for self-deleted questions: [Edit a self-deleted question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213632)

Comment: And here I thought you were perfection personified. Illusion shattered ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I edited a deleted post, and then had it reinstated. http://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/4951/revisions

Comment: @Frank That's an answer, though. Rules are different for questions.

Comment: @Raff Oh okay. thnx

Comment: @Martijn Pieters  how do i flag them if i cant find them?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters  Anyone have a clue how i find them^^^?

Comment: @Timothy: recent posts (created in the past 2 months) are listed in your profile (go to your or answers or questions tab and find a link at the very bottom). You can flag any of your existing posts, flag *that* and ask a moderator to undelete your deleted posts.

Comment: @Martijn The ones i need undeleted are about 6 months old.

Comment: @Timothy: then pick another post that isn't deleted.