# Why can't I access the source of revisions for my own deleted posts?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, revisions-list, view-source

I can see the revision history, but clicking the provided "source" links by each revision 404s. For example, [this revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/dd6f48e9-0c81-4e5f-bd7a-6337fab5ee64/view-source) was unavailable while its corresponding answer was deleted.

Comment: You probably suspected this, but users with 10k *can* actually access this link.

Comment: When Jeff deployed [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42069/why-cant-i-view-the-revisions-of-my-own-deleted-answer), he probably missed/forgot about the "source" option